# Convert ToDateTime fail when publish to Webserver

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, datetime

I got this problem about Convert String to Datetime.
This is my code:

```
@if (Convert.ToDateTime(item.EXPIRED_DATE) <= DateTime.Now)
{
    <td><span style="color:red;">@item.EXPIRED_DATE</span></td>
}
```

When I run it on my localhost, it worked. But when I publish it on Webserver, I got this Error Message:

> Exception Details: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

And this is item.EXPIRED_DATE value

> "31/01/2018"

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(item.EXPIRED_DATE, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Why you got the error you have mentioned?

As you could read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e(v=vs.110).aspx) `Convert.ToDateTime`, since the value you pass is not null, would invoke `DateTime.Parse` and return its result. The `DateTime.Parse` as it is mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) (look at the question: *Which method do I call?*) parses a date and time string by using the conventions of the **current culture**. So your program current's cutlure is not has not a format for DateTime as the one you want to use. This is why you have to use `DateTime.ParseExact` method providing the correct format.

Comment: Or should I convert DateTime.Now to "dd/MM/yyyy" ?
Is that easier?

Comment: @TrọngNguyễn you are welcome. I am glad that I helped :)

Comment: <= wouldn't be impacted by culture as `DateTime`s don't have a format, strings do.